# I need an efficient way to process a backspace in a C# text box

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port

I have a GUI that has a text box that is used to display the output of a device that is connected to a serial port.  There are times when that device will output a "ticker".  This is a sequence of character-backspace-character that results in the appearance of an analog clock's hands turning using the characters '|', '/', '-' and '\' along with space and backspace so that those characters overwrite each other.  Anyway, this doesn't process well in a textbox because it doesn't deal with the backspace the same way a terminal would.
So, I've spent almost a full day trying to figure out how to get around this to no avail.
Yes, I know I can do...

```
textBox_CONSOLE.Text = textBox_CONSOLE.Text.Substring(0,textBox_CONSOLE.Text.Length-1));
```

but that's extremely inefficient; hence I want a better method (if possible).
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You make it efficient by assigning the SelectedText property.  Use the Select(int, int) method first to select the last character.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int len = textBox_CONSOLE.Text.Length;
        if (len == 0)
            return;
        textBox_CONSOLE.Select(len - 1, len);
        textBox_CONSOLE.SelectedText = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)?

Comment: Don't do this.  It's very unreliable since it always sends to the active application.